# Ansible "Module Failure" on all sudo commands

Tags: ansible

I'm messing around with the Ansible tutorial commands and changing some of the parameters just to see what happens.

I can successfully do:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

And I can successfully do:

```
ansible all -a "/bin/echo hello"
```

But when I modify the example to do anything involving sudo privilege, it fails with a nondescript MODULE FAILURE message.

```
ansible all -a "/bin/echo hi" --sudo
ansible all -a "/usr/sbin/shutdown -h now" --sudo
```

On the remote machine, the user I am connecting as does have membership in the wheel group and can successfully execute sudo commands locally.

What am I doing wrong? (CentOS 7)

Comment: Funnily enough, the following does work (though makes use of arguments that I thought were deprecated): ansible all -a "/usr/sbin/shutdown -h now" --su --su-user=root --ask-su-pass

Comment: What version of Ansible are you using?  Does it work using `--become` instead?  Does your user have password-less sudo privileges?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem.

This outputs module failure:

```
ansible all -i <server>, -m command -a "/<command> <args>" -u <user> -b
```

These work:

```
ansible all -i <server>, -m command -a "/<command> <args>" -u <user> -b -K
```

-- but it asks sudo password

```
ansible all -i <server>, -m command -a "/<command> <args>" -e 
"ansible_ssh_user=<user> ansible_ssh_pass=<pass> ansible_sudo_pass=<pass>" -b
```